# How should I fill a hole in an exterior wall?

Tags: walls, exterior, hole

I noticed a good sized hole in an exterior wall that allows wires and things to go from my AC unit into my basement.

The problem is that the hole is a good deal larger than it needs to be and there is nothing sealing the hole, so I can see sunlight clearly through the hole.

What should I use to fill this hole in my wall preserving the important stuff going through the hole?

*Click for full size*

[image: hole in the wooden exterior wall]

Comment: Picture?  What is going through the hole, how big is the hole?

Comment: Also, what material is used for the wall?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use [Duct Seal](https://www.idealindustries.ca/products/duct-seal-2.html)

[image] [image]

I'm surprised whoever installed the AC unit didn't use it, it's used all the time by Electricians and HVAC technicians.

It does not harden; so unlike foam, it can be easily removed and replaced if you have to add/remove wiring/plumbing.

Comment: FYI: "Duct Seal" link is broken.

Answer (score 6):

Usually all that is needed is a good outdoors silicon caulk. You can get a clear type or a paint-able white type.

Comment: "Do your best and caulk the rest!"

Comment: I like 'great stuff' for this sort of application.  try the 'doors and windows' version.

Comment: Foam gap fillers (like Great Stuff) are very useful but are not the best way to seal exterior surfaces, because they break down faster when exposed to sunlight and/or water. An exterior-grade caulk is the way to go for a longer-lasting seal.

Comment: Painted Great Stuff last much longer.